# export dataset to xslx and include filters

Tags: r

Im trying to create a xlsx file out from a dataset (18 columns). cant seem to have the filter flag to work. The file that is created does have the fixed row that i need but not the filter

```
write.xlsx(main.df, 
           "febrero2021.xlsx",
           row.names = FALSE, 
           firstActiveRow=2, 
           colWidths = "auto",
           withFilter = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                          TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                          TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                          TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                          TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                          TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug in `openxlsx`, since according to `?write.xlsx`, the `...` should be passed to `writeData` (and, I'm inferring, `writeDataTable`).

Regardless, I can confirm the behavior. Both of the following commands

```r
write.xlsx(mtcars, "mt.xlsx", asTable=TRUE, row.names=FALSE,
           firstActiveRow=2, colWidths="auto", withFilter=FALSE)
write.xlsx(mtcars, "mt.xlsx", asTable=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, 
           firstActiveRow=2, colWidths="auto", withFilter=TRUE)
```

produces

[image: excel data table with filters]

(And frankly, it looks like it's more than just `withFilter=` that's affected ... `colWidths="auto"` is not being passed, either.)

However, if you create it manually with `writeDataTable`, it works.

```r
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "mtcars")
writeDataTable(wb, "mtcars", mtcars, withFilter=TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "mt.xlsx")
```

[image: excel data table, still with filters]

```r
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "mtcars")
writeDataTable(wb, "mtcars", mtcars, withFilter=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "mt.xlsx")
```

[image: excel data table with filters off]

**Note** for reproducibility of my code: I also added `overwrite=TRUE` to each of the `saveWorkbook`, since it will by default not overwrite existing files. I chose to keep it out to prevent inadvertent mistakes.

Comment: thanks. any workaround for the flags `firstActiveRow=2, colWidths = "auto"` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not look like they are in `writeDataTable`, unfortunately. BTW: I submitted a bug report on this, https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/151. I suggest that you add a feature-request there to add those two options to `writeData(Table)`.

Comment: It appears to be fixed: https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/pull/164 (untested).

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
write.xlsx(main.df, 
           "febrero2021.xlsx",
           asTable = TRUE,
           row.names = FALSE, 
           firstActiveRow=2, 
           colWidths = "auto",
           withFilter = TRUE)
```

Comment: For me, this doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: this doesnt fix my issue

Comment: It's probably a problem with the class of the object you are trying to put in the excel sheet. Could you give a short example of your data?